# difference between while loop vs. single use of diamond operator in perl

Tags: perl

I am confused at the following:

```
<>; print;
```

vs.

```
while(<>){print;}
```

The first one does not print anything, but second one does. Doesn't `<>` always store the input read into `$_`?

Thank you.

Comment: First one is in scalar context, isn't it?

Comment: `$a = <>; print $a;` prints the first line.  So I guess '<>;' doesn't update $_.

Comment: in the first example, `<>` is in void context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The diamond file input iterator is only magical when it is in the conditional of a while loop:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '<>; print;'
<ARGV>;
print $_;
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while (<>) {print;}'
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

This is all documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)

Answer (score 8):

It does not except as the condition of a `while` statement.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while(<>) { print }'
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '<>; print'
<ARGV>;
print $_;
-e syntax OK
```

[`perlop`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#I/O_Operators) documents that the auto-assignment to `$_` only happens in this context:

> Ordinarily you must assign the returned value to a variable, but there
>   is one situation where an automatic assignment happens.  If and only if
>   the input symbol is the only thing inside the conditional of a "while"
>   statement (even if disguised as a "for(;;)" loop), the value is
>   automatically assigned to the global variable $_ , destroying whatever
>   was there previously.  (This may seem like an odd thing to you, but
>   you'll use the construct in almost every Perl script you write.)  The
>   $_ variable is not implicitly localized.  You'll have to put a "local
>   $_ ;" before the loop if you want that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html (Talking about $_) :

"The default place to put an input record when a  operation's result is tested by itself as the sole criterion of a while test. Outside a while test, this will not happen."